# How to convert one dimensional array into multidimensional?

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array like

```
$arr($name=>"vinu",$street0=>"xxx",$street1=>"yyy").
```

i need to convert this as

```
$arr1($name=>"vinu",$street=>array("xxx","yyy")).
```

How can i do this?

Comment: How do you create this array? Is it just statically, or from some external source (database,xml)

Comment: What do the variables `$name` `$street0` and `$street1` look like ?

Answer (score 3):

like

```
foreach($ary as $k => $v)
    if(preg_match("~(.+?)(\d+)$~", $k, $m))
        $out[$m[1]][$m[2]] = $v;
    else
        $out[$k] = $v;
```

basically, if a key is "something and digits" put its value into `result[something][digits]` otherwise simply copy the value into the result array

Comment: Can you please explain your regexp, it's not that intuitive